# Running TorBB on host machine while running Whonix VM setup as guest on the same physical box

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, thin-clients, tor

I've currently set up Whonix VMs using Virtual Box on OS X 10.11.6. Before that I was using a Bitcoin-qt with Tor Browser Bundle.

Now I'm having question what is a best way to use bitcoin+tor setup in my case?

Could it be dangerous for my anonymity to run TorBB+Bitcoin-QT setup on host(OSX) machine while running Whonix VM setup at the same time?

I guess the best way is to transfer somehow my bitcoins to Whonix Workstation, and set up there something like a thin wallet (electrum or multibit)? Or could I just leave the TorBB+Bitcoin scheme on my OSX, running it just for Bitcoin, while using Whonix for all other anonymous stuff (like browsing etc.)?

Hey, community, how would you address this situation?

Thank you very much!